# selecting distinct data with similar data in two columns

Tags: sql, oracle10g, distinct

I have a table `XXXTEST`

```
table XXXTEST (C1 varchar2(50),C2 varchar2(50), dist NUMBER )
```

with this sample data:

```
('Pune','Mumbai',128);
('Mumbai','Pune',128);
('Pune','Nashik',200);
('Nashik','Pune',200);
('Nashik','Mumbai',250);
('Nashik','Mumbai',250);
```

I want to select the city combination only once i.e from "pune-mumbai" and "mumbai-pune" only one row must be selected.

I tried using self join but that didn't help. So please if you can provide with a query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the cities alphabetically and then use a plain `DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct 
   least(c1, c2) as c1, 
   greatest(c1,c2) as c2,
   dist
from XXXTEST
```

Answer (score 1):

If c2 > c1, check that not the switched combination exists, using NOT EXISTS, with switched c1/c2 columns:

```
select distinct c1, c2, dist
from XXXTEST t1 
where c1 < c2
  or  not exists (select * from XXXTEST t2
                  where t1.c1 = t2.c2 and t1.c2 = t2.c1);
```

Executes as:

```
SQL>CREATE TABLE XXXTEST (C1 VARCHAR(10),C2 VARCHAR(10), dist integer);
SQL>INSERT INTO xxxtest VALUES ('Pune','Mumbai',128);
SQL>
SQL>INSERT INTO xxxtest VALUES ('Mumbai','Pune',128);
SQL>INSERT INTO xxxtest VALUES ('Pune','Nashik',200);
SQL>INSERT INTO xxxtest VALUES ('Nashik','Pune',200);
SQL>INSERT INTO xxxtest VALUES ('Nashik','Mumbai',250);
SQL>INSERT INTO xxxtest VALUES ('Nashik','Mumbai',250);
SQL>    select distinct c1, c2, dist
SQL&    from XXXTEST t1 
SQL&    where c1 < c2
SQL&      or  not exists (select * from XXXTEST t2
SQL&                      where t1.c1 = t2.c2 and t1.c2 = t2.c1);
C1         C2                dist
========== ========== ===========
Mumbai     Pune               128
Nashik     Mumbai             250
Nashik     Pune               200

                  3 rows found
```

Comment: That query is incorrect. It will only give a unique row for the exact duplicates. Totally different from OP's requirement.

Comment: Yeah, of course. Too early in the morning here... Will have a cup of coffee and then edit.

Answer (score 0):

**HIERARCHICAL method**:

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT c1,
  2    c2,
  3    dist
  4  FROM
  5    ( SELECT c1, c2, dist FROM xxxtest CONNECT BY nocycle prior c1 = c2
  6    )
  7  WHERE c1 > c2
  8  /

C1         C2               DIST
---------- ---------- ----------
Pune       Mumbai            128
Nashik     Mumbai            250
Pune       Nashik            200

SQL>
```

Also, let's say if the distance between the cities are unique, I think you could simply select the DISTINCT distance rather than making it complex with the cities and their combination.

**ANALYTIC method**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT c1,
  3      c2,
  4      dist,
  5      row_number() over(partition BY dist order by dist) rn
  6    FROM xxxtest
  7    )
  8  SELECT c1, c2, dist FROM DATA WHERE rn = 1
  9  /

C1         C2               DIST
---------- ---------- ----------
Pune       Mumbai            128
Pune       Nashik            200
Nashik     Mumbai            250

SQL>
```